# What is the difference between $filter and facet in Azure Search

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

Quite new to **Azure Search**, and just wondering what is the difference between facet and filter?

Say I have a product table, and it has category and subcategories. If I want to return things under one category, should I use `$filter` or use facet? What is the difference between these two?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Filter is used to restrict which documents are returned by a query. Faceting is used to produce summaries of field values across those documents. Details are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/searchservice/Search-Documents) and you can find more general info about how to use faceting and filter together [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/search-faceted-navigation).

For your specific example, to retrieve documents for one category, use a filter. If you then want to see how many of those documents there are for each sub-category of that category (for example), use facets.

Answer (score 7):

If you compare with SQL, filter equals Where clause and facets are like groupBy, although not exactly.

Below is an example:

[image]

Now if you want to know count of each country in the list you can query as below.

```
{
    search: '*',
    queryType: 'full',
    facets: [
      'country',
    ],
    count: true,
    searchMode: 'any',
    }
```

It will return complete data along with facets data like:

`{ "count": 2, "value": "India" }`

else to get data of only country as India, you can query as below.

```
{
    search: '*',
    queryType: 'full',
    filter: "country:India",
    count: true,
    searchMode: 'any',
    }
```

and you get only 2 data in return.